# how to compute correlation between two samples

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation

I'm trying to compute the correlation between two samples (rows) in DataFrame type. I've found some codes that compute the correlation between features(columns), eventually, it converts the matrix to sorted List, and then remove correlation with itself. which I want the same thing for samples.

```py
correlations_all = train_df[features].corr().abs().unstack().sort_values(kind="quicksort").reset_index()

correlations_all = correlations_all[correlations_all['level_0'] != correlations_all['level_1']]

output:
level_0        level_1        0
var_0          var_1          0.50
var_0          var_4          0.45
var_10         var_4          0.4
```

so how to do this in python?

Comment: Can you specify   "converts the matrix to sorted List, and then remove correlation with itself. which I want the same thing for sample"  part ?

Comment: I'll edit the question, so you can see it.

Comment: @AlperenTahta instead of printing correlation matrix, it prints a List like the outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum your answer is

```
pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1).T.corr().drop(range(0,df.shape[1]),axis=1)[0:df.shape[1]+1]
```

**Detailed explonation:**

Create a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=100, size=(10, 5)),columns=list('abcde'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=100, size=(10, 5)),columns=list('fghjk'))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
a   b   c   d   e
0  47  68  60   8  27
1  52  36  50   0  46
2  21  53  55  43   0
3  32  63  42  37  38
4  91  95  28  81  55
5  68  14  16   5  27
6  51   2  73   8  49
7   2  83  54  77  61
8  44  89  87  93  42
9  75  50  78  31  80

>>> df2
    f   g   h   j   k
0  40  62  68   2  24
1  55   9  64  37  39
2  18   5  11  14  79
3  36  14  39  11  66
4  63  95  87  49  81
5  29  20  76  32  90
6  19  48  13   0  81
7  79  55  32   8  17
8  93   3  33   7  53
9  85  30  50  14   2
corr()
```

There is a `corrwith()` function that The first one computes correlation with another dataframe.

`corr()` is more useful in your situation. But `corr()` computes it with itself. Because of that first we concat 2 df.

**Output:**

```
>>>pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   j   k
0  47  68  60   8  27  40  62  68   2  24
1  52  36  50   0  46  55   9  64  37  39
2  21  53  55  43   0  18   5  11  14  79
3  32  63  42  37  38  36  14  39  11  66
4  91  95  28  81  55  63  95  87  49  81
5  68  14  16   5  27  29  20  76  32  90
6  51   2  73   8  49  19  48  13   0  81
7   2  83  54  77  61  79  55  32   8  17
8  44  89  87  93  42  93   3  33   7  53
9  75  50  78  31  80  85  30  50  14   2
```

`corr()` method computes correlation between columns. To compute between rows first take transpose and drop the parts of df that you don't want to see.

```
pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1).T.corr().drop(range(0,df.shape[1]),axis=1)[0:df.shape[1]+1]
```

**Output:**

```
pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1).T.corr().drop(range(0,df.shape[1]),axis=1)[0:df.shape[1]]
              5         6         7         8         9
    0  0.154824  0.161153 -0.006838 -0.301014 -0.125625
    1 -0.405248 -0.344024  0.413258  0.284815  0.367698
    2  0.146049 -0.390763  0.165186 -0.358735 -0.245411
    3 -0.018887 -0.084056 -0.239326  0.061516  0.488869
    4 -0.338686  0.256093  0.455395  0.741626 -0.130878
```

To extract single row

```
def compute_corr(df,i):
    print(f"Correlation between {i}'th sample and other samples")
    return df.T.corr().loc[i]
```

**Output:**

```
x= pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1).T.corr().drop(range(0,6),axis=1)
compute_corr(x,0)
Correlation between 0'th sample and other samples
0    1.000000
1    0.590134
2   -0.983648
3   -0.894758
4   -0.463191   
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I hope this time that code is your need.

Comment: I want to check which sample has more effect in predicting. something like this.

Comment: however, what you've done is almost what I wanted. the difference is, I want to give it a row, and it computes the correlation of this row with all rows in DataFrame.

Comment: I see,  t you can find what you actually wan in this output. For example first row of output gives you correlation between first sample and all other samples.

Comment: the reason for my goal is, DataFrame is partitioned. if I recombine them, it will take huge time, to do so for other rows.

Comment: this is closer than before, but still not what I want to achieve. in your example, consider your DataFrame as df1, and we have another DataFrame as df2, now I want to correlate between df2[i] and df1.

Comment: I edited the code. For future questions please clearly specify your question.